# Как сынтерпретировать сообщение от пользователя python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot, ос

Пишу телеграмм-бота на Python через telebot. Этот бот должен будет интерпретировать код, который пришлет пользователь. 
Вот так выглядит функция, интерпретирующая код:

```py
def interpreter(message):
    file = open('programmes.py', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
    file.write(message.text)
    file.close()

    conclusion = os.system('programmes.py')

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, conclusion)
```

При запуске в консоль выводится вывод кода ( например: Код: print(5+5) | Вывод: 10 ). А бот высылает пользователю цифру 0. Независимо оттого, какой код. Будь то: a = 5 или print(4-3).
[image: Та самая функция]

[image: Вот, что присылает бот, при выполнении кода]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `os.system` возвращает код завершения программы. Код `0` означает, что программа завершилась без ошибок.

Для выполнения произвольного кода и получения результатов, есть функции `exec`, `eval` и модуль `ast`.

***Пример:***

```py
code = '9*8'
result = eval(code)
print(result)        # 72
```

---

Но я Вам крайне **не советую** исполнять произвольный код от пользователей. Это может привести к компрометации всей системы.

Comment: Так код ведь код пользователя будет работать на сервере и никак не будет связан с моей системой. Ведь так?

Comment: @SkyGuy А сервер не является Вашей системой? :D Просто представьте, что будет, если пользователь передаст строку "`import os; os.system('rm -rf')`" и она исполнится...

Comment: @nomnims12 Я пробовал создать "пульт-бота" от моего компа. он работал если я его запускал лично, а когда я его залил на сервер, он перестал работать

Comment: @SkyGuy Код исполняется там, где запущен  (логично). То есть, чтобы исполнять команды на своём ПК, на нём Вы и должны хостить бота.

Comment: Ну да. То есть если я запущу код на своем пк, то он будет выполнять команды у себя. но если я залью бота допустим на хероку, то моим пк уже никто управлять не сможет. Верно?